# What is the minimum required in order to make hardware accel works on Funtoo?

Tags: kernel, x11, opengl, funtoo

I'm trying to make hardware 3d acceleration works on Funtoo, but with minimum use flags enabled as possible.

Now I'm testing Funtoo on a RX Vega 54, but I have other computers with others vendors' cards that I'll try later.

When I boot on Ubuntu, all `glxgears`, `glmark2` and `glmark2-es2` gives around 8000 FPS, on Funtoo there is no `glmark2` but `glxgears` gives about 600 FPS, when chroot to Ubuntu over Funtoo kernel and xorg-drivers it gives about 1600 FPS on `glxgears` and 400 FPS on `glmark2-es2`, but `glmark2` doesn't even work.

I belive the problem is the renderer, running `glxinfo | fgrep 'renderer string'` gives the following result:

- Ubuntu booted: `OpenGL renderer string: Radeon RX Vega (VEGA10, DRM 3.33.0, 5.3.0-51-generic, LLVM 10.0.0)`
- Funtoo booted: `OpenGL renderer string: Software Rasterizer`
- Ubuntu chrooted on Funtoo booted: `OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 128 bits)`

[Configuration (make.conf and package.use)](https://gist.github.com/tiagoapimenta/8ccca48b4406fbe025cc2692c9932828)

[Some other metrics](https://gist.github.com/tiagoapimenta/10dcc839ae68ec9695bf3cb2118189f2)

Look, the challenge is not being able to enable any use flag globally, if one is strictly required only the minimum set of packages should be configured.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have not enabled hardware acceleration on Funtoo.

You should take a look on Funtoo instructions for the open-source amd drivers. It shows the set of kernel configuration settings needed to be able to properly compile as modules and use those drivers.

You can find a link here: [Package:Radeon Video Drivers](https://www.funtoo.org/Package:Radeon_Video_Drivers)

In a nutshell: if kernel is already properly compiled you need to emerge the Radeon-ucode or linux-firmware packages as well as xf86-video-ati package.